# Applying proxy settings to applications on Linux, proxy is running mainly for browsers under Windows

Tags: linux, proxy, centos, vpn

One of our customer's network system is running under some VPN.
Our system should run under Linux. We deployed two systems for them inside their network, which is protected under firewall and proxy architecture. We need to update all applications at the two servers to latest version under Cent OS. But one thing making us in trouble is that their secure system told us we could only access the internet through their proxy server. After some explorations, we found they only run some Windows applications via that proxy server such as Internet Explorer. We are hoping to get help on accessing their proxy platform under Linux. We need at least "wget" and "yum" to access proxy. Unfortunately they could not provide us help under Linux.

We have attempted to applied proxy settings to wget and yum, which returns only 403 forbidden. Below is solutions that we have tried.

```
$ export http_proxy={proxy IP they provided}
$ wget --proxy-user={their account name, an email address} --proxy-password={password they provided} {URL we need to request}
```

The only returned message is 403 forbidden.
(They did free the firewall restrictions for us, that we could touch that proxy server indeed.)
We also applied such settings to /etc/yum.conf, set the proxy variables with the account information they provided to us, but still returned 403 forbidden error.
Another thing I want to figure out is that because their account name is an email address, commands and settings on Linux often prompted lexical or parsing error that it could not tell the "@" apart from other parts. (For some commands, "@" is used to tell the host name or IP address.)

They did not deploy any graphical interface under server so we could not apply proxy via browser.

It would be so appreciated if anyone provides a solution.

P.s. I am quite a newbie to Linux so maybe there are some other things I have not tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{proxy IP they provided}` - This implies you provided neither a proxy protcol nor a port number? If so then that's likely the problem. It should be, e.g.

```
http_proxy='http://192.168.0.1:8080/'
```

or using embedded credentials:

```
http_proxy='http://username:password@192.168.0.1:8080/'
```

But it's also possible that the proxy might only support NTLM authentication - this is only supported under recent versions of wget. Not sure about yum.

However if there's a requirement that the system you provided to the client be able to connect outwards for updates, and you have a requirement from the client to update the system, and you can't do that because the client can't provide a suitable internet connection, then it sounds like time to start billing the client for a site visit.

Comment: I tried different protocols and different ports, both of which returned nothing. I think it indeed is the time to start billing them. Thanks :)